# When is $x \mapsto \int_{V}F(x,y)dy$ smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Letting $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be closed and bounded, suppose that the map $F:U\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $F(x_0,-):V\to \mathbb{R}$ and $F(-,y_0):U\to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth for all $x_0 \in U$ and $y_0 \in V$. I know that it is *not* necessarily the case that $F$ is smooth.

However, do we have that the map $U \to \mathbb{R}$ sending $x \mapsto \int_{V}F(x,y)dy$ is smooth?

Comment: Why the differential geometry tag? Can you show that the map is even continuous?

Comment: Seems like a Calc III type exercise about limits of functions of two variables. How about considering quotients of polynomials in two variables in a square like $[0,1]\times[0,1]?$